# Getting wireshark to see network (uplink) traffic?

Tags: monitoring, switch, wireshark, packet-sniffer

I have wireshark on a win 7 toshiba laptop plugged in to a hp procurve switch.  I set the port the laptop is plugged in to as a 'monitor' port, monitoring all the other ports.

I have 1 other computer plugged in to the switch and then an uplink line to the rest of the network.

I am seeing traffic between the switch and the computer , switch and network, but no traffic to web sites or even to/from other machines on the LAN.

For example, if I access the http admin screens of the switch, I see that traffic.

However, if I access this site, I am not seeing that traffic.

Even between this machine which is running a web server and another machine running a web server on the LAN uplink I can not see any traffic when accessing using a browser.

It is almost as if I need to enable an additional setting somewhere to say 'show me uplink traffic too, not just traffic within the switch'  ??

Comment: From what I can understand, you are connected on a monitor port on SWITCH A, trying to see traffic that is on SWITCH-B that is connected to SWITCH-A through an uplink switch?

Comment: Literally, laptop connected to port 1 (monitor port) on SWITCH-A.   Desktop machine connected to port 2 on SWITCH-A.   Cable running from port 3 SWITCH-A to port x on SWITCH-B (uplink to rest of network / internet).   I want to see *ALL* traffic going through port 2 and 3 on SWITCH-A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it to work - I plugged everything in to ports 1-24 (port 1 my monitor port) -
 I found a reference on another site,

On the 2650/2650-PWR switches, ports are grouped as follows: 1-24 + 49, and 25-48 + 50

http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1301660131365+28353475&threadId=1338535

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applied to your switch model, but take a look at this HP documenation:
http://cdn.procurve.com/training/Manuals/2910-MCG-Feb09-B-Monitor.pdf

It sounds like you might also need to be monitoring the VLAN itself as a source for your monitoring.